# Is there any method to find img in divs

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

following code i am trying for getting divs
but i want the img in that divs

```py
from typing import List

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
`launch the browser`
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/home/earth/Downloads/Python/chromedriver_linux64 (2)/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://demo1.devmarketidiot.com/")`getting url`
driver.maximize_window()`maximize the window`
time.sleep(2)
html=driver.page_source`getting page source`
#file = html.read()
S= BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')``
print("........Divs...........")
mydivs=S.findAll('div')`find all divs present in that page source`
print(len(mydivs)) 
for i in mydivs:
    print("i:",i)
```

please giv me the solution to find img or any component in that divs`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code, it will print the value of `src` attribute from the `img` tag inside all the `div` tags:

```
imgs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div img")

for img in imgs:
    src = img.get_attribute("src")
    print(src)
```

Output:

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg%20xmlns=%27http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%27%20version=%271.1%27%20width=%27270%27%20height=%2758%27/%3e

https://demo1.devmarketidiot.com/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2FMI-logo.e581cfae.png&w=640&q=75

https://static.demo1.devmarketidiot.com/content_pages/85aa12e1-c2cd-4984-89a0-7981a2526bd41673622255509.jpg

https://static.demo1.devmarketidiot.com/content_pages/fbbef982-4fc1-449c-91ee-0db3b6daa25f1673622653654.jpg
```

Comment: how can i use this for perticular div?